# Why does my default option disappear from my select?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ubAPmJoMQaKBLvWSsmTv?p=preview**

[image]

---

In my app when I first toggle open this dropdown:

[image]

After closing and reopening the dropdown:

[image]

---

**My markup:** I have my `ng-init="vh.loadedViews[0].description"` setup, not sure why this changed :(

```
<section class="saved-views-modal" ng-show="vh.loadSavedModal">
    <header><h1>Select a saved view</h1></header>

    <div class="select-style">
        <select name="select"
                ng-init="vh.loadedViews[0].description"
                ng-show="vh.viewsAvaliable"
                ng-model="vh.description"
                ng-change="vh.chooseView(vh.description)">
                <option ng-repeat="view in vh.loadedViews"
                        ng-init="vh.description=vh.loadedViews[0].description"
                        value="{{ view.description }}">{{ view.description }}</option>
         </select>

         <select ng-hide="vh.viewsAvaliable" name="select">
            <option selected="selected" value="No saved views">No saved views</option>
         </select>
     </div>

    <button class="btn-green" ng-click="vh.loadView()">Load View</button>
    <button class="btn-green" ng-click="vh.deleteView()">Delete View</button>
</section>
```

---

I just noticed there is this error inside of the markup `?undefined:undefined ?`

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a Live example of the problem?

Comment: Added plunker! Here, the first item never shows up: https://plnkr.co/edit/ubAPmJoMQaKBLvWSsmTv?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide ng-init in select instead of option

Like this

```
  <select name="select" ng-init="description=loadedViews[0].description" ng-model="description" ng-change="chooseView()">
    <option ng-repeat="view in loadedViews" value="{{ view.description }}">{{ view.description }}</option>
  </select>
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/HhuO4ErCN5W7U3tQGXaS?p=preview)**</kbd>

But it's better to use **[`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)**

Like this

```
  <select name="select" ng-init="description=loadedViews[0].description" ng-model="description" ng-options="view.description as view.description for view in loadedViews" ng-change="chooseView()">
  </select>
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/cK9uy0oElB8lbc2e09kx?p=preview)**</kbd>